# Using wxWidgets with MinGW, CMake and Code::Blocks

Tags: windows, cmake, codeblocks, wxwidgets, mingw-w64

I configured wxWidgets in CMake and built it with MinGW-x64. After building binaries I used the command `mingw32-make install` (as used in OpenCV) and It was automatically installed with the file arrangement shown below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets
├───include
│   └───wx
│       ├───android
│       ├───aui
│       ├───dfb
│       ├───generic
│       ├───gtk
│       ├───gtk1
│       ├───html
│       ├───meta
│       ├───motif
│       ├───msw
│       ├───osx
|       |...
└───lib
    └───gcc_dll
        └───mswu
            └───wx
```

But after the installation, I provided the parameters `Compiler` and `Linker` at `Code::Blocks-> Settings-> Compiler -> Search Directories` , but it gave errors while compiling a sample program, indicating the non-standard procedure.

I don't know the next step to associate the libraries and include files with Code::Blocks correctly. I have already googled it and most web-results use makefile.gcc in procedure. How to use wxWidgets in CodeBlocks after that?

Comment: Any error messages would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Be advised that CMake is not an official way to build wxWidgets. You can however build your own software using this tool. CMake incorporation is started fairy recently and will be available (fully tested) in version 3.2. (hopefully).

Now I don't know what error message(s) you received in C::B, but you have to select exactly the same options for the new project as the one you build wxWidgets with. I.e. if you supply SHARED=0 during wxWidgets compilation you absolutely have to select SHARED=0 in the C::B project. And so forth.

Without the exact error message that the best suggestion you will get.

Also, you didn't mention you version of wxWidgets. Please do so in the future, especially since you are working with the IDE that does not immediately utilize the latest version of wx.

HTH.

Comment: `SHARED` is a definition that only wxWidgets' makefile's understand. Due to all wxWidgets samples use a `makefile` it's here where the same options are required. Using the compiler directly does not requires these definitions, but some others  like `__WXMSW__`

Answer (score 0):

Because each project (you have created a project, right? C::B requires it) may need different libraries and options I prefer not to use "global" C::B settings (apart from 'Toolchain executables').

Instead go to `Project-->Build options`. Check that the 'Selected compiler` is the one you want.

the tab `Compiler settings` refers to your compiler (g++), not to wxWidgets requirements. Take a look at the flags. Other options like `-mthreads` may be required.

The tab `Linker settings` is good for all Windows .dll, such as kernel32, user32, winmm, and about a dozen more.

If you have different targets, such as "debug" and "release" then wxWidgets libs are different (the "debug" ones have a `d` near the end of each name). Thus you must add different wx libs for different targets. Select one target (big box at left) and again in the `Linker settings` tab add those libs (wxmsw31u_core, wxbase31u, etc, or just the "big monolitic" one if you built this instead of several files) Seems you only have a "release" target, select it.

To instruct the compiler & linker about where it can find these wxWidgets files (.dll or .a) and its headers use the `Search directories` tab. Again, different targets use different dirs.

The compiler searches for `.h`, in your case add the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include` and also `C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_dll\mswu`

For the linker (in `Linker`sub-tab) add `C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_dll`

The `Resource compiler` sub-tab, for your `.res` file (likely you use one) uses also some wxWidgets headers, so add the same `C:\Program Files (x86)\wxWidgets\include`

Don't forget that wxWidgets uses some definitions.

 Go to tab `Compiler settings` sub-tab `#defines` and add entries: `__GNUWIN32__` and `__WXMSW__`

For more options read `yourwxdir\docs\msw\install.txt`